# Tell me how to rewrite the condition from the example using the IF operator?

Tags: pine-script

Please tell me how it will be with the use of the usual IF operator. I'm confused and can't figure out what's going on

```
dir := close > shortStopPrev ? 1 : close < longStopPrev ? -1 : dir
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally:

```
if (close > shortStopPrev)
    dir := 1
else if (close < longStopPrev)
    dir := -1
else
    dir := dir
```

Of course, the final `else` and its block isn't necessary when using this style. It's only needed in the one-line form since its if/then structure is entirely on the value side of the assignment.